# iOS Present View Controller Within Popup

Tags: ios, ipad, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

So I have my main view controller. That view controller has a bar button item with a storyboard segue with kind set as Present As Popover.

This all works as expected. But when you tap another button within that popover view controller it presents the view full screen. I want it to display within the popover. Like push/display on top of the existing popover bounds.

How can I achieve this?

I only want this behavior on iPad. But I think it does that by default.

**Edit**

I'd prefer to do this all in the storyboard but am willing to do it with Swift code as well if that is what's required.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero

Comment: @elk_cloner That looks like an animation library. Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: This third party can help you: https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only with Storyboard.

1) Create an UIViewController (blue) and ctrl + drag (mouse) from your UIBarButtonItem to the UIViewController and select "present as Popover" (like you did).

2) Click on the UIViewController (blue) and click on Editor->embed in->Navigation Controller (this will be trick to let the next controller stay in the popup)

3) Create a second UIViewController (green)

4) Create a UIButton in the first UIViewController (blue) and ctrl + drag from the button to the second UIViewController (green) and select "show"

At the end it should look like this in Storyboard:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

[image]

If you want the PopOver without the navigationBar you can use in the blue controller:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

and to go back from the green to the blue view you can use in the green controller:

```
@IBAction func backToBlueController(sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Additional:

If you don't want to use the popUp you could also change the segue kind from the barButtonItem to the navigationController to

> Present Modally

and the presentation to something like

> Form Sheet

in Storyboard.

[image]

At a glance, you should always use an UINavigationController to manage your navigation, even if you don't need the navigationBar, because the navigation controller provides you a navigation stack from where you can pop and push into it.

[UINavigationController Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to remove the nav bar at the top? It just doesn't fit with my design really. I might do a redesign later to make it fit with the app style but not now. Also inside both the `blue` and `green` views I have a button that runs `dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`. Is there anyway on the `blue` view to get that to close the entire popover, and on the `green` view to go back to the `blue` view? I know this can probably be fixed with the nav bar but it just doesn't fit into the app style. Plus on iPhone the nav bar doesn't have a close button on the `blue` view.

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true will remove the navBar. (In the blue controller) and self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true) in the green controller will pop the green back to the blue

Comment: Sorry, in my country it's 11 pm now and i can only look on Monday how to dismiss the popOver, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Dismissing the popover I was able to do with `dismiss`. I guess my final question is the `green` view can be displayed without the navigationController and without the popover. Can I just do something like `if self.navigationController?` and put `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` in there and in the else statement put `dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`? Would that revert to `dismiss` if there is no navigationController and it was displayed from another section without the navigationController or popover?

Comment: I think you can use self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) on the blue to dismiss the entire popOver

Comment: I think I figured it out! Just have to work on implementing it all. I will up vote your answer now. I normally don't accept answers and award the bounty till it's over (just so you are aware). Thank you very much for your help!! It would be awesome if at some point you could edit your answer to include all of the information in these comments. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Create a `IBAction` of your `UIBarButtonItem`, and in action:

```
- (IBAction)popupAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];  // I don't use segue
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popvc = vc.popoverPresentationController;
    popvc.delegate = self;
    popvc.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popvc.barButtonItem = sender; // if UIBarButtonItem
    // if view
    // popvc.sourceView = sender;
    // popvc.sourceRect = sender.bounds;

    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`:

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}

- (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController{
    return YES;
}
```

Swift:

```
@IBAction func popupAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let vc = UIViewController.init()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    let popvc = vc.popoverPresentationController
    popvc?.delegate = self
    popvc?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any
    popvc?.barButtonItem = sender
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200)

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}

func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This works on both iPad and iPhone.

Result:

[image]

Popover another viewController in a popover controller:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Swift

Comment: Same problem. The `UIBarButtonItem` displays the view controller as a popover but when you click on a button inside of the popover it doesn't display inside the popover it displays full screen.

Comment: You mean popover another vc inside a popover vc?

Comment: Yep. So the `UIBarButtonItem` displays a popover. And inside of that view controller/popover I have buttons. I want those buttons to display view controllers inside of the original popover, not as full screen view controllers. And I'd prefer to just use the storyboard to achieve this instead of using code. But if I have to use code that is fine too. Using storyboard is just so much cleaner.

Comment: If  not `UIBarButtonItem `, you need use `sourceView` and `sourceRect`. And I add a image of popover another view controller.

Comment: When I click on that button inside of the popover I want the popover view to be replaced with that new view controller. Or the new view controller to be pushed onto the existing popover. I don't want 2 popovers. 2 popovers is the current behavior when I use the Storyboard Present As Popover.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it - EzPopup (https://github.com/huynguyencong/EzPopup), a Swift pod. Just a few lines of code:

```
// init YourViewController
let contentVC = ...

// Init popup view controller with content is your content view controller
let popupVC = PopupViewController(contentController: contentVC, popupWidth: 100, popupHeight: 200)

// show it by call present(_ , animated:) method from a current UIViewController
present(popupVC, animated: true)
```